# Why can't I use a Linq query on a Visio Masters collection?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to do the following Linq query on a [Visio Masters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms368289.aspx) collection:

```
List<string> allMasterNames = (from master in myStencil.Masters select master.NameU).ToList<string>
```

I get the following error:

> Could not find an implementation of
>   the query pattern for source type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Masters'.
>   'Select' not found.  Consider
>   explicitly specifying the type of the
>   range variable 'master'.

From reading around this error seems to occur when the queried object does not implement `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>`. Is that the case here, or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is because it's not `IEnumerable<T>`, `IQueryable<T>` and it doesn't have its own custom Select method written.

Contary to popular believe you **don't** have to implement those interfaces to have LINQ support, you just need to have the methods they compile down to.

This is fine:

```
public class MyClass { 
  public MyClass Select<MyClass>(Func<MyClass, MyClass> func) { ... } 
}

var tmp = from m in new MyClass()
          select m;
```

Sure a `.ToList()` wont work though ;)

As you solving your problem try using the `Cast<T>()` extension method, that'll make it an `IEnumerable<T>` and allow you to LINQ to your hearts content.

Comment: I added the answer & by the time I did, you got what you needed :)

Answer (score 1):

As the exception message suggests, consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'master'.

```
from Visio.Master master in myStencil.Masters select master.NameU
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) ...

```
public class MastersClass : IVMasters, Masters, EMasters_Event, IEnumerable
{
  // more
}
```

None of the others are `IEnumerable<T>` either.  But, good ol IEnumerable is there, so you can for each.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot try this piece of code.

```
(from master in myStencil.Masters.Cast<Masters> select master.NameU).ToList<string>)
```

The gist is to use `Enumerable.Cast` method, to convert a non-generic list to a generic one.
Does that work?